# Is the passenger capacity of the A350 really only 250 pax?

Tags: cabin-design, airbus-a350, new-airplane, seating-capacity, configuration

I read online that the capacity of an A350 was 250 passengers, but I took the max cabin width and length of an A350-900XWB, and I ended up with a 400 passenger capacity in a 4-class layout.

- Economy was a 3-3-3 configuration, with 2.48 feet seat pitch
- Premium was a 2-4-2 config. with a 3 feet seat pitch
- Business was a 2-2-2 config. with a full 6 feet seat pitch
- First class had a wide 1-2-1 configuration with a full lie flat bed to make for a 7 feet seat pitch

Yet, I still got a capacity way higher than 250 of 234 economy seats, 54 premium seats, 42 buisness seats, and 16 first class seats, and the total for 346 passengers + 8 crew! Yes, I included washrooms for all classes, emergency exits, and the galleys. What does the capacity of 250 really mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Airbus themselves give max passenger seating 440, and typical seating 3-class 300-350, for the A350-900. https://www.airbus.com/aircraft/passenger-aircraft/a350xwb-family/a350-900.html

The undeveloped A350-800 is listed with 276 passengers. Maybe that's where you got your 250 number.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I always wondered why it could only carry 250,  and now I know that's now true! And love how you included the official Airbus website in your answer.